# Android - OnClick usage in subclass instead of super

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I've currently ran into a problem where I have a super class called 'PopupWindow' which initialized a AlertDialog.Builder and shows it to the user. However I have two sub-classes called 'CallInitializePopup' and 'CallReinitializePopup'. I would like to "outsource" the input listener(onClick) to these sub-classes and have code individual to the sub class called there.

Snippet of PopupWindow:

```
alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);

    //'setTitle' simply sets the title of the popup
    //'setMessage' sets the description, usually a short instruction on what the user should enter
    alert.setTitle(POPUP_LOGIN_TITLE);
    alert.setMessage(POPUP_LOGIN_TEXT);

    //Initialize EditTexts that will populate our popup and set the hints for each
    stockSymbolEditText = new EditText(mainActivity);
    stockSymbolEditText.setHint(STOCK_SYMBOL_HINT);
    stockPriceEditText = new EditText(mainActivity);
    stockPriceEditText.setHint(STOCK_PRICE_HINT);

    //These TextViews are only there to give the user guidance on what to include regarding the Spinners(since the Spinners doesn't include hints)
    buyOrSellTextView = new TextView(mainActivity);
    buyOrSellTextView.setText("  Alert - buy or sell");

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 35);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mainActivity);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.addView(stockSymbolEditText, layoutParams);
    layout.addView(stockPriceEditText, layoutParams);
    //layout.addView(updateIntervalTextView);
    //layout.addView(updateIntervalSpinner);
    layout.addView(buyOrSellTextView);
    layout.addView(buySellSpinner);
    alert.setView(layout);

    //Finally we show the popup
    alert.show();
```

My first OnClickListener approach in a sub class:

```
private void setInputListener()
{
    Log.d("setInputListener", "called");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Set Alert", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Store the values in current variables
            stockSymbol = stockSymbolEditText.getText().toString();
            stockPrice = stockPriceEditText.getText().toString();
            //String selectedInterval = updateIntervalSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            buyOrSell = buySellSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Log.d("Alert dialog submitted", "stockSymbol: " + stockSymbol + " - " + "stockPrice: " + stockPrice + " - " + "buyOrSell: " + buyOrSell);


            //Only call 'AssignStockCall()' once stockSymbol, stochPrice, and buyOrSell are initialized in the onClick method
            //Create a new StockCall with the new info the user included
            AssignNewStockCall();
        }
    });

    //With 'setNegativeButton' we don't want to do anything, the user doesn't want to add a new stock call
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Canceled
        }
    });
}
```

**The first approach does not show any buttons, and If I were to take a guess that's because we initialize the inputListener after and in another class than when we initialized the AlertDialog.Builder.**

The second approach:

```
    //These onClick classes are used by the PopupWindow class, they are assigned to the specific button by supplying a new instance of the classes
final class CancelOnClickListener implements
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        Log.d("onClick", "Cancel");
    }
}

final class SetAlertOnClickListener implements
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        Log.d("onClick", "Set Alert");
    }
}
```

**This approach doesn't work with the super class, since the super class needs to know if it's a 'CallInitializePopup' or a 'CallReinitializePopup' and there is no such communication between super and sub class.**

***Any help is highly appreciated!***

Answer (score 1):

You will ran in to many problems like this in future if you will not change your coding style. You should learn SOLID principles of object oriented programming at first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29 And then study design patterns. Derek Banas youtube channel comes at help, since he very clearly explains design patterns.
In your case you are violating Open Closed principle (from SOLID principles). Super class should not depend on subclass.
I wouldn't use inheritance at all in your situation. If you need different implementation of the same action, use Strategy or State design pattern.

## Example using Strategy pattern

```
class PopUpWindow implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    /**
    *
    *
    *    other code
    *
    **/

    /** You don't need two different listers. Use same listener since 
        you can determine which button has been pressed from *int which*  **/

    alert.setPositiveButton(this);   
    alert.setNegativeButton(this);
    
    interface Strategy
    {
        public void doWork();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
         switch(which)
         {
             case dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE :
                   getPositiveButtonStrategy().doWork(); break;
             case dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE :
                   getNegativeButtonStrategy().doWork(); break;
             
         }
    }
    
    private Strategy getPositiveButtonStrategy()
    { 
        if (/** conditions to implementation NO1**/)
              return new Strategy
                         {
                            @Override
                            public void doWork()
                            {
                                /** your implementation NO1 **/
                            }
                          }
                      else return new Strategy
                                      {
                                         @Override
                                         public void doWork()
                                         {
                                            /** your implementation NO2 **/
                                         }
                                      };
              /** you can implement as much Strategies as you need **/                       
        }
    }

    private Strategy getNegativeButtonStrategy()
    { 
        if (/** conditions to implementation NO1**/)
              return new Strategy
                         {
                            @Override
                            public void doWork()
                            {
                                /** your implementation NO1 **/
                            }
                          }
                      else return new Strategy
                                      {
                                         @Override
                                         public void doWork()
                                         {
                                            /** your implementation NO2 **/
                                         }
                                      };
              /** everything in your class is available for "Strategies" **/                    
        }
    }
}
```

Without knowing SOLID and Design Patterns it is close to impossible to write understandable, maintainable, bug-free code

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I'm quite new to OOP concepts and I will definitely check out Derek Banas videos.